# Expire user session using Firebase Authentication

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication

### How do I get user sessions logged into my system expire every 1 hour with AngularFireAuth?

In the configurations of my system I want to enable the authenticated user to be able to configure the time that the session expires.

To log in to the system I am using the following code.

```
  signIn(user: User) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
  }
```

I've been looking in the documentation but I can not figure out how to apply this to my system.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence?hl=pt-br

I would like to know how to do this from ***AngularFireAuth***.
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md

Answer (score 3):

Firebase Authentication sessions don't expire, the refresh tokens are valid indefinitely. The short-lived ID tokens are re-checked periodically (about once an hour), but there is no API to control how long that process succeeds.

You have a few options though:

- The only control you have over the user's authentication session from the client-side API is to sign the user out.
- Alternatively, you can use server-side code to explicitly [revoke an individual refresh token through the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens).
- If you must have an expiring token, consider creating your own sign-in provider for Firebase Authentication. In that case you can [control when the token expires through the `exp` claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).